# Mail through domain IP or the server IP - which PTR record?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, reverse-dns

I have one lingering issue with DNS for my domain, which sits at a static IP address on a server at my hosting company which has a few other domains sharing another IP address.

When I check my DNS at dnsstuff.com I get one error:

```
All connections to Mailservers port 25 have failed. The standard port 
for SMTP transactions is 25, so your servers should be operating on that 
port. It is recommended that it be fixed in order for your mail service 
to operate properly. The Mail Servers that failed are:

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx | failed message send with: messaging failure: Time out 
occurred or Remote server closed connection prematurely
```

Other online tools warn me that no reverse-DNS PTR record exists for my domain.

I asked my hosting company about it and they basically said "Right now all email is going through your cloud.example.com domain and through the IP address of the server.  That IP does have a PTR record, so email will be fine.  We recommend this instead of having email go through each static IP address and associated domain".

So...is that an 'ok' answer or should I politely ask them again to please configure email for the domain I have at the other static IP address, to use that IP address -- and have a PTR record for reverse resolution?

Comment: Right now it sounds like all the MX record for your domain aren't listening on port 25 or are dropping the connections. If you can provide us with the actual domain it would be so much easier to help.

Comment: Thanks - and I expected the port 25 error because that is exactly true -- nothing is set up for that IP/domain.  My hosting service is telling me that all mail is being handled by the "base server" IP address and the cloud.example.com domain, and I should be ok with that configuration.  I believe I prefer the actual domain with dedicated IP address to be handling mail -- thus my question - am I right or is the hosting service right?